# How to use mailto on a mobile web app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, email, mailto

I'm trying to use `mailto` from a web app that needs to work on mobile devices (angularjs with ionic framework), so that on click, it opens the default email app.

My first attempt was to use `href="mailto:my@mail.com"` but that didn't work.

So, I did some reseach, and tried all the method I was able to find, but none of them worked.

Here's what I tried:

> - href="mailto:my@mail.com"
> - href="mailto:my@mail.com" data-rel="external"
> - href="mailto:my@mail.com" target="_blank"
> - href="mailto:my@mail.com" data-rel="external" target="_blank"

Then I also tried with `onClick` and javascript

> - onclick="window.location='mailto:my@mail.com';return false;"
> - onclick="window.location='mailto:my@mail.com';return false;" target="_blank"
> - onclick="window.location='mailto:my@mail.com';return false;" data-rel="external"
> - onclick="window.location='mailto:my@mail.com';return false;" data-rel="external" target="_blank"

They all works on a desktop, but none of them worked on Android (can't test iOS at the moment)

How can I achieve this? `mailto` to work on desktop, ios and android? Thanks a lot.

PS: If it helps, I'm building the app using `cordova` and I'm also using `crosswalk`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option you listed should work. Make sure your `config.xml` has en entry for something like this:

```
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
```

This will ensure that `mailto` is handled by your whitelist.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot. Quick question: do you know if it is possible to attach files easily, or if I have to add other entries in the config.xml to allow them?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean file attachments to the email? If so, then no. You'll need to do that with the email app which opens. The only things you can do from the `mailto` is add a subject or placeholder email body content. Like this: `mailto:someone@gmail.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject?body=Body%20content%20here `

Comment: For sending attachments you can use the following plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer)